# How to change URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource called Book, then I have domains like:

```
   domain.com/books/272
```

But I want to change it to

```
   domain.com/stories/272
```

Only for the URL, don't need to change controller, classes etc.

In the routes I have

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

  map.root :controller => 'static'
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends really on what you have already.

Use this code to your routes file: (in the case of the original URL of `books` replaced by `stories`)

```
#resource routes
map.resources :books, :as => :stories
#named routes
map.books 'stories/:id'
```

Without defining routes the only option I can think of - which seems terribly wrong - is to add a new controller which inherits from your books controller. You'd need to go through your application and change the controller name used to generate paths or URLs as seen in the following example:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

class StoriesController < BooksController
```

Personally, I would recommend you take the time to define your routes but I guess this depends on how large an application you're working with.

This guide will help you understand routing in RoR: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 8):

In rails 3, I believe you would do the following:

```
resources :books, :path => 'stories'
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest, efficient and practical way of implementing this fix. This is a more up to date answer regarding this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Its called named routes and is done in your `config/routes.rb`

In your routes file:

```
map.stories 'stories/:id', :controller => 'books', :action => 'show'
```

Then in your view you can access this route with:

```
<%= link_to book.name, stories_path(book) %>
```

Make sure you change `book.name` to whatever name you want. also make sure you passing `book` as a local variable to the routes path.

You can also change the `:id` to be more SEO friendly with `to_param` in the respective model.

In your model:

```
 def to_param
     "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\s/, '_').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase}"
 end
```

Also make sure you replace `name` with an attribute that the book model actually has.

Comment: There's a much better way to do this by using the `:as` option.