# How to change namespace URI in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm newbie in RoR and I'd like a bit of help here.

I have the following URI:

```
http://localhost:3000/abouts/2
```

And the next in Route:

```
resources :abouts, only: [:show]
```

I'd like to show the information of "about/2" in another page, for example:

```
http://localhost:3000/new_about
```

Regards!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535654/how-to-change-url-in-rails
I think it's the same problem you're having now.

Comment: What you are describing is not a Rails convention but you can match any url in `routes.rb`. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316048/custom-url-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply map the desired URL to your existing action:

```
get 'new_about', to: 'abouts#show', id: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own routes in rails. You'd do something like :

```
get "/new_about" => "controller#action"
```

I would suggest sticking to the Rails way of doing things though unless it's only a few number of pages and you specifically need them to be named differently.